# What does underscore mean in PHP variables?

Tags: php

I see them on `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_db` and so on. What does it mean?

Comment: Nothing really. It's a convention to point out the superglobals, but other than that, it has no meaning

Comment: Just a naming convention and doesn't necessarily mean anything in particular. Usually it's chosen to indicate something is private, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the time any variable that follows the convention $_ with all uppercase letters will be a [PHP Predefined Variable.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php)

All of the following are predefined variables:

```
$_SERVER — Server and execution environment information
$_GET — HTTP GET variables
$_POST — HTTP POST variables
$_FILES — HTTP File Upload variables
$_REQUEST — HTTP Request variables
$_SESSION — Session variables
$_ENV — Environment variables
$_COOKIE — HTTP Cookies
```

There is also a convention you may find in older code that protected and private variables in classes are prefixed with either _ or __.

As Peter notes below in the comments though, using __ typically denotes magic functionality (constants and methods), and is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED by the PHP development team that using __ as a prefix may break in the future due to conflicts with new functionality.

Comment: Any identifier starting with __ is meant to be *magic* in PHP. Use it only to get *magic* functionality. Users should **not** define their own identifiers starting with __. Also in classes _ prefix might indicate private or protected field, but it is just a convention.

Comment: __ denotes magic functionality for methods but not variables.  I've seen some very old code where _ means is a convention to identify protected variables and __ is a convention to identify private variables.  

Not something I suggest, but just trying to make ihan aware.

Comment: Not only methods. Consider `__DIR__`, `__FILE__`, `__halt_compiler()`, thats why i used *identifiers* instead of *methods*

Comment: Correct, but those would be magic constants. I was referring to something like :

class Mock {
   var $publicVar;
   var $_protectedVar;
   var $__privateVar;
}

Like I said, OLD coding conventions from yesteryear! :)

Comment: You are totally right, but note that i used word *identifier* to be more generic, as identifier could be const name, method name, or whateva name:)

Comment: I updated my answer above to reflect this conversation ... good points.

Answer (score 2):

Usually variables that are already declared by PHP are considered global.

User created variables and functions that start with underscores can be interpreted as private - but thats just a convention.